# Excepetion in data event handler binding on read stream

Tags: node.js

I am getting Error while attaching 'data' event handler on read stream.
If I place this handler at other place as mention in the code (before pipe), I don't see any exception.

Please help me, what is wrong here?

```
var Readable = require("stream").Readable;
var readStream = new Readable;

readStream.on('data',function(chunk){console.log(chunk);}); //Error

readStream.push('first data');
readStream.push('second data');
readStream.push(null);

//if I place data event handler here, no Error is seen
readStream.pipe(process.stdout);
```

//getting error while binding data event handler

```
events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error: not implemented
    at Readable._read (_stream_readable.js:446:22)
    at Readable.read (_stream_readable.js:320:10)
    at Readable.<anonymous> (_stream_readable.js:745:45)
    at Readable.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:92:17)
    at emitDataEvents (_stream_readable.js:771:10)
    at Readable.on (_stream_readable.js:692:5)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/pk/node/readableStream.js:12:12)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't simply instantiate `Readable` stream, as it has no valid `_read` method implemented. If you want just to push some data to it (without performing real IO), just set it to noop:

```
readStream._read = function () {};
```

Comment: Great, just another basic question. If I add this _read function, data will be read after very push operation and nothing will remain to pipe to stdout. Pleaser correct me If I am wrong.

Comment: yes, you need to pipe before, or remove `data` listener